# Cypher query - recommendations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have problem with build query (in Cypher neo4j). I want to see other products who was bought by client, who bought product 'cap'. In my graph model, I should get in result 'boots', but I can't get this. Here is my graph model:

[image]

How to build this query? Can you give me some hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work to find all clients who purchased a cap, and all other products they may have bought.

```
MATCH (a:Client)-[:PURCHASED]->(:Cart)-[:ADD]->(p:Product {name: "cap"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:PURCHASED]->(:Cart)-[:ADD]->(p2:Product)
WHERE p <> p2
RETURN a, p, COLLECT(p2) AS otherProducts
```